# Can Magento1 or Magento2 use VUE.js?

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to use  VUE.js in Magento1 or Magento2?

Is any one used this, please share me example.

Thanks

Comment: You can review the repo of VUEjs with magento 2 from https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront And demo from https://demo.storefrontcloud.io/